# Random sessions using Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

all,

I use Fiddler for developing and debugging Web apps, and I find that random stuff shows up in the list of "sessions" after I turn off `Capture Traffic`.  It's perhaps a few items every ten or fifteen minutes.  I know this is a really broad question, but is there some way to figure out why these things are showing up and what they are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Capture Traffic` setting controls whether or not Fiddler is registered as the system's proxy server. *Most* clients (Internet Explorer, etc) will react to the system proxy setting at runtime, so that when you disable the `Capture traffic` setting, they'll stop sending traffic to Fiddler.

However, some clients (particularly .NET applications) do not react to proxy setting changes and always use whatever proxy was set when the client was started; they'll continue to send traffic to Fiddler until the client is restarted.

You can examine the `Process` column in Fiddler to see what client isn't properly reacting to changes in the system's proxy setting.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, Eric.  The next time I am using Fiddler (probably in the next few days), I will give this a shot.

Comment: I've had a few more of these today, and the `Process` column is empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you right-click the session and choose Properties, what's the ClientIP value? Can you share some of the traffic in question (File > Save Session Archive)?

Comment: I'm going to forward the information to someone who deals with IT security here. I looked up the IP addresses for X-CLIENTIP and X_HOSTIP, and they seem unusual.  I'm going to mark this as the right answer, since you did lead me down the right path in your subsequent comment.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have web pages open that periodically hit the server from within javascript (ajax calls), fiddler captures that traffic and that's what you're seeing.